# SQL create table issue in Access

Tags: sql, database

So I am very new at SQL and I really cannot find what is going wrong. I am doing this in access.

```
  CREATE TABLE BOAT_SLIP
(
SLIP_ID NUMBER (4) PRIMARY KEY,
MARINA_NUM CHAR (4),
SLIP_NUM CHAR (4),
LENGTH NUMBER (4),
RENTAL_FEE NUMBER (8),
BOAT_NAME CHAR (50),
BOAT_TYPE CHAR (50),
OWNER_NUM CHAR (4)
 ) ;
```

I know I am going to feel like a complete moron.. but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NUMBER doesn't have a character length.  If you delete the (4) and (8) from the right of SLIP_ID, LENGTH, and RENTAL_FEE, the table creates just fine.

Comment: I literally just figured that out at the same time. Although I don't remember seeing that in my textbook... silly textbook. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

In the older versions of Access (up to 2002, at least), you could paste standard SQL `CREATE TABLE` statements into the SQL view of a query, and Access would do the Right Thing with it. It even handled char(n) declarations the same way standard SQL did. So I'd expect this to work, although I'm not sure I'm translating your data types correctly.

```
CREATE TABLE BOAT_SLIP
(
  SLIP_ID integer PRIMARY KEY,
  MARINA_NUM CHAR (4),
  SLIP_NUM CHAR (4),
  LENGTH integer,
  RENTAL_FEE currency,
  BOAT_NAME varchar(50),
  BOAT_TYPE varchar(50),
  OWNER_NUM CHAR (4)
);
```

Consider adding `NOT NULL` constraints on most of those columns.